# REFERENCE ERROR html e node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pessoas = [];

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(request, response, next) {
  response.render('index', { title: 'Node.js com Express' });
});

router.post('/cadastrar-pessoa', function (request, response, next) {
    
    hash = {
           nome: request.body.nome,
      sobrenome: request.body.sobrenome,
            cpf: request.body.cpf,
       telefone: request.body.telefone,     
       endereco: request.body.endereco,

       
    };
    pessoas.push(hash);
      


    response.render('index', { title: 'cadastrar-pessoa', pessoas: pessoas });

});


module.exports = router;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/validacao.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    h1>Cadastro em tempo de execução</h1>

  <fieldset id="formCadastro">
   <legend>Cadastro de pessoas</legend>
   <form action="cadastrar-pessoa" method="POST" onsubmit=" return validacao()">
    <div>
     <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
     <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /> 
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome:  </label>
     <input type="text" name="sobrenome" id="sobrenome" /> 
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="cpf">CPF:  </label>
     <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" /> 
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="telefone">Telefone:  </label>
     <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" /> 
    </div>
    <div>
     <label for="endereco">Endereço:  </label>
     <input type="text" name="endereco" id="endereco" /> 
    </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" /> 
    </div>
   </form>
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Pessoas cadastradas</legend>
   <table border="1" id="registros">
    <tr>
     <td>Nome</td>
     <td>Sobrenome</td>
     <td>CPF</td>
     <td>Telefone</td>
     <td>Endereço</td>
    </tr>
    <% for (i=0; i<pessoas.length; i++) { %>
     <tr>
      <td><%= pessoas[i].nome %></td>
      <td><%= pessoas[i].sobrenome %></td>
      <td><%= pessoas[i].cpf%></td>
      <td><%= pessoas[i].telefone%></td>
      <td><%= pessoas[i].endereco%></td>
     </tr>
    <% } %>
   
   
   
   </table>
  </fieldset>

  </body>
</html>
```

o ERRO:

C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\views\index.ejs:54 52| Endereço 53|  >> 54| <% for (i=0; i < pessoas.length; i++) { %> 55|  56| <%= pessoas[i].nome %> 57| <%= pessoas[i].sobrenome %> pessoas is not defined
ReferenceError: C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\views\index.ejs:54
    52|                     Endereço
    53|

> > 54|                 <% for (i=0; i < pessoas.length; i++) { %>
> >         55|                     
> >         56|                         <%= pessoas[i].nome %>
> >         57|                         <%= pessoas[i].sobrenome %>

pessoas is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:633:12), :20:22)
    at returnedFn (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:668:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\routes\index.js:7:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\node\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Comment: complementando abaixo, IMPORTANTÍSSIMO você aprender a usar o debugger pra inspecionar seus erros. Por exemplo, o erro acima claramente diz "pessoas está vazio", então você analisa  o código passo a passo pra saber porque a variável está vazia. Recomendo explorar as opções de debug do VS Code (e usar esse editor se ainda não o está fazendo)

Answer (score 0):

JCSR,

Em seu GET, você fez da seguinte forma:

```
response.render('index', { title: 'Node.js com Express' });
```

Porém sua index espera receber `pessoas` (mesmo que vazio), e você só enviou no POST, para corrigir essa situação, você deve enviar `pessoas` tanto no GET quanto no POST (correto):

```
response.render('home', { title: 'Node.js com Express', pessoas: pessoas});
```

Ou até mesmo enviar vazio, depende de sua lógica/implementação:

```
response.render('home', { title: 'Node.js com Express', pessoas: []});
```

Isso já corrige o seu erro e sua página será renderizada.

---

Existe outros pequenos problemas, sua tag h1 está incorreta:

```
h1>Cadastro em tempo de execução</h1>
```

Basta abrir a tag corretamente:

```
<h1>Cadastro em tempo de execução</h1>
```

Em seu for, você não declarou a variável i:

```
<% for (i=0; i<pessoas.length; i++) { %>
```

Basta declarar a variável com let:

```
<% for (let i=0; i<pessoas.length; i++) { %>
```